# Render view on click Reactjs

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have created a overlay element and I want it to appear when a certain input field is clicked. I'm new to react so it's not clear to me how I should do it.

This is the view that should appear

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import pro_pic from '../../Resources/img/Anon.jpg';
import menu_drop from '../../Resources/img/drop.png';

class QuestionOverlay extends Component {


    render() {

        return (

            <div id="overlay">

            </div>



            )
    }
}

export default QuestionOverlay;
```

The click event is here

```
 render() {

        function popup_ques(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            alert("render overlay view");
        }

        return (
            <div className="middle_div">

                <input className='post_data_input' placeholder="Ask your question here" ref="postTxt"
                       onClick={popup_ques}/>



            </div>


        );
    }
```

So when I click the input field, the overlay I have created should appear instead of the alert I have given.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    overlayVisible: false
  }
}

render() {
    function popup_ques(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        this.setState({
          overlayVisible: true
        });
    }

    return (
        <div className="middle_div">
            <input 
                 className='post_data_input' 
                 placeholder="Ask your question here" 
                 ref="postTxt"
                 onClick={popup_ques}/>

            {this.state.overlayVisible && <QuestionOverlay />}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Your function has to be pure, so, based on a state you get an UI render, if you want to insert something, you change your state, but your render function remains the same.

However that approach effectively constructs a new overlay every time you show it, if you want to keep the state perhaps it is better to keep the component but change it's rendering:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class QuestionOverlay extends Component {
    render() {
      if(!this.props.visible) {
        return null
      }

      return (<div id="overlay"/>)
    }
}

export default QuestionOverlay;
```

And the container:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    overlayVisible: false
  }
}

render() {
    function popup_ques(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        this.setState({
          overlayVisible: true
        });
    }

    return (
        <div className="middle_div">
            <input 
                 className='post_data_input' 
                 placeholder="Ask your question here" 
                 ref="postTxt"
                 onClick={popup_ques}/>

            <QuestionOverlay visible={this.state.overlayVisible}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```